# How to test GET and POST api which requires user logged in pytest Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I have created a fixture to create user and auto login in conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_password():
   return 'strong-test-pass'




@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def create_user(db, test_password):
    def make_user(**kwargs):
        employee = e_ge_employee.objects.create()
        kwargs['password'] = test_password
        if 'username' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['username'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        if 'employee' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['employee'] = employee
        return e_ge_user.objects.create(**kwargs)
    return make_user

@pytest.fixture
def auto_login_user(db, client, create_user, test_password):
    def make_auto_login(user=None):
        if user is None:
            user = create_user()
        client.login(username=user.username, password=test_password)
        return client, user
    return make_auto_login
```

and then wrote a testcase to check get api in test_urls.py

```
class TestUrls:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('param', [
        ('generate_token'),
        ('roi_report')
    ])
    def test_generate_token_url(self, auto_login_user, param):
        url = reverse(param)
        client, user = auto_login_user()
        print("client",client)
        print("user",user)
        resp = client.get(url)
        print(resp)
        assert resp.status_code == 200
```

It is giving me the error
**{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}**

in my api_views I am using authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, ]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ] these two classes

Can someone please provide me with the solution.....Thanks in Advance

Comment: The question is too broad. What have you tried and what specific problem have you run into? Also, how does a user authenticate after logging in? Is it a token, a cookie, something else?

Comment: I have updated the Question now check is it clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your `auto_login_user` as follows to `force_authenticate` the user.

**first import APIClient from rest_framework.test**

```
# import
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

@pytest.fixture
def auto_login_user(db, create_user):
    api_client = APIClient()
    api_client.force_authenticate(user=create_user)
    return api_client
```

and now update your test as follows

```
def test_generate_token_url(self, auto_login_user, create_user, param):
        url = reverse(param)
        user = create_user
        resp = auto_login_user.get(url)
        print(resp)
        assert resp.status_code == 200
```

if this doesn't work maybe the problem is with the `create_user` fixture